# When clicks on close button it should stop redirecting using alertify?

Tags: javascript, alertify, alertifyjs

It is redirecting to profile page when I click the close button. But it goes `onclose` event section and it should not refresh the page as It `returns false` but redirecting to profile page.

```
alertify.alert().setting({
                'title': 'Message',
                'label': 'Ok',
                'message': 'You have not yet enabled Appointment on your profile?',
                'onok': function () {
                    document.location.href = "/profile";
                },
                'onclose':function(e){
                   return false;//It should stop redirecting on profile page
                }
            }).show();
```

Error: When I click on `Ok` or `Close(X)` both events are firing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of `alertify` this is the default functionality of `alert onok`  event.

So when `onok` event is being called in alert It automatically calls `onclose` event to close the dialog.

Comment: Can `onok` and `onclose` invoke individually? Or there is another solution.

Comment: It's better to use `confirm` dialog in this type of situation when you need `onok` and `onclose` to work individually.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 'onclose':(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();    //It will stop redirecting on profile page
    return false;//
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's giving an error `uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'preventdefault' of undefined`

Comment: console.log(e) <-- what do u see ?

Comment: i have update the code , i used arrow function to resolve binding issue if any please use updated code

Comment: I need to see your whole code , please give me link to acces it ,share here

Comment: This is working code, when page is loaded a popup opens. There can click on ok or close buttons.

Comment: as expected , e is undefined that is why e.preventDefault() is not working .Ideally when you call handler then the event is passed to binded method. Which is not happenig in your case. can you show how you are calling onclose ?

Comment: 'onclose':(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();    //It will stop redirecting on profile page
    return false;//
}